# How to insert from an extended class

Tags: java, jdbc

My information is read in via CSV for "banking information", A person CSV is

```
5                       
1,Tony,Stark,C,tonys,naslvj34-t934,stark@hmmm.org;tony@gmail.com;tostark55@yaho.com
2,Patrick,Hart,C,phart2,sdlwgl5034i52,hart@hmmm.org;hart1@who.org
3,Tom,Baker,E,bake95,kweojtnefq567,
4,Kevin,Black,C,keb765,prjhohier99,black@mail.org
5,Alex,Codd,E,alcodd,andlqjr78,codd@DBMS.org;alex@gmail.com
```

my Account CSV is,

```
5
1,313001,S,35881.12
2,313002,G,772400.34
3,313003,C,250002.15
4,313004,P,96310.66
5,313005,P,15624.15
1,313006,C,39950.99
```

In the Account CSV the 2nd token is My "Account type", so S = "Savings" G = "Gold Savings" C = "Checkings" and so on. When reading these in my CSV parser class, an object was made of the types, so A Checking class was made and when the CSV was tokenized when token[2] was equal to "C".

My Persons class is set up as so, excluding my getters and setters

```java
private int personId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String type;
private String usrname;
private String password;    
private ArrayList<String> emails;

public Person(int personId, String firstName, String lastName, String type, String usrname, String password,
        ArrayList<String> emails) {
    super();
```

And my Account class is set up as so.

```java
private Person accountHolder;
private int accountNumber;
private double currentBalance;
 
public Account() {}

public Account(Person accountHolder, int accountNumber, double currentBalance) {
    this.accountHolder = accountHolder;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
}
```

This is one of my example account types (there are multiple)

```java
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {

    public CheckingAccount(Person p, int i, double d) {
        super(p,i, d);
    }
```

This is my database adder

```java
public static void DbAddAccount(Person personId, Account accountHolder){
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseInfo.URL,  DatabaseInfo.USERNAME, DatabaseInfo.PASSWORD);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    
    String accountQuery = "insert into Account (accountId,accountNumber,currentBalance,type,personId) values (?,?,?,?,?);";
        
    PreparedStatement accountPs = null;

    ResultSet accountKeys = null;
    
    int accountId = 0;

    try {
        //These are my prepare Statements for my queries
        accountPs = conn.prepareStatement(accountQuery);
        accountPs.setInt(1, accountId+ 1 );
        accountPs.setInt(2, accountHolder.getAccountNumber());
        accountPs.setDouble(3, accountHolder.getCurrentBalance());
        accountPs.setString(4, ??????????????????????????????????);

        accountPs.setInt(5, personId.getPersonId());
                            
        accountPs.executeUpdate();
        accountPs.close(); 
        conn.close();
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

JDBC is not adding anything when running.

Comment: This won't compile: `accountPs.setString(4, ??????????????????????????????????);`

Answer (score -1):

I think your code has following issues:

1. **Account Object:**
   Object is missing field to store "Account Type"
2. **Setting incorrect account type** in **DbAddAccount** method
   At line  accountPs.setString(4, ??????????????????????????????????);
   you are number of question marks (without enclosing in quote to make string) as account type which appears it is not correct.

- series of ??? wont get converted to string without enclosed in quotes.
- Even if you enclose in quotes, I think it wont be intended account number;

**Solution**
**for Issue 1**; declare account_type in Account Object.

**for issue 2**; instead of using  accountPs.setString(4, ??????????????????????????????????);
use:
accountPs.setString(4, account.getAccountType());